# Magento Connect Extension not approved

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-connect

I have uploaded a Magento Community Extension on Magento connect .. but now its status showing "Not Approved". how can I know what is the reason for not approved. and how this all process works ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whether an extension is approved or not-approved, an email is sent to the email address listed on your community member account. For your particular instance, please check your email for a rejection letter and tips of corrections required for final approval.

As long as the extension meets the [Magento Connect Guidelines](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/create_your_extension/), your extension will be approved. Also, per our terms, you must be a qualified Magento partner to be able to submit EE compatible extensions.

Magento Connect is a free marketplace where anyone can share an extension that would benefit the Magento ecosystem at large. We do not validate nor test the functionality of an extension. We do however provide a review tool where we encourage users (merchants and developers alike) to share their experiences with the extensions used and interactions with the extension developers.

You can follow the Magento Connect Team on twitter [@magentoconnect](https://twitter.com/magentoconnect)

You can also reach the team at connect at ebay.com

Comment: Having the same issue here - `Not Approved` status and no email with any reason is received.

Answer (score 4):

If your extension has the status 'Not Approved', most probably nobody took a look at it to validate it.
When someone rejects your extension you get an e-mail with reasons why the extension was rejected. Here is an example with what I've got some time ago:

> ...
>   In order for us to be able to approve your submission, please resubmit
>   with the following corrections per our guidelines.
>
> The following items must be corrected:
>
> Developer Avatar Needed: Add a Developer Avatar to your profile. It
>   must look professional; however it does not necessarily need to be a
>   picture of you.
>   ....

Also, there is always the possibility of sending an e-mail to Magento asking about your extension.